# Print forms across multiple pages

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have 3 printing methods: printa, printb , and printc (each printing a form) . All the 3 forms need to be printed across multiple pages. How can I print across 3 pages?

I know that we need to use the the event handler and use currentpage and e.hasmorepages but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep track of the page number.  You set it to 0 in the BeginPrint event and increment it every time that PrintPage is called.  Like this:

```
    int pageNumber;

    private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
        pageNumber = 0;
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) {
        ++pageNumber;
        e.HasMorePages = true;
        switch (pageNumber) {
            case 1: printa(e); break;
            case 2: printb(e); break;
            case 3: printc(e); e.HasMorePages = false; break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it can be pretty obscure. Here's how I did it for [printing Reporting Services](http://theruntime.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2007/12/07/printing-reporting-services-2005-reports.aspx) reports (the MetaFile image array in the code below).

```
public void Print()
{
    if (emfImage == null || emfImage.Count <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("An image is required to print.");
    }

    printer = printer.Trim();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(printer))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("A printer is required.");
    }

    printingPage = 0;
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
    pd.Print();
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Metafile page = emfImage[printingPage];
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(page, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);

    e.HasMorePages = ++printingPage < emfImage.Count;
}
```