# How can I print mutiple pages?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, reporting, reportviewer

How can ı print multiple pages with C#? I am printing an invoice with reportviewer(.rdlc) for one invoice... On a datagrid user select more than one invoice and right click contextmenu and go to print all invoices..(User will not open invoice) Is this possible? I searched too much time but didnt find anything!

Comment: possibly duplicate.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777659/print-forms-across-multiple-pages